# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre las etiquetas "nombres" y "sustantivos"? Renombremos [nombres] a [nombres-propios]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas

Las etiquetas  [nombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres) y [sustantivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustantivos) tienen descripciones muy parecidas.

> **nombres**
>
> Preguntas relacionadas con nombres propios o sustantivos.
>
> Questions about names or substantives.

Y

> **sustantivos**
>
> Para preguntas sobre sustantivos, sus usos, significados, etimología o
>   su gramática.
>
> For questions about substantives, its uses, meanings, etymology and
>   grammar.

¿Cuál debería ser la línea que las separa?

Para mí, [nombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres) debería referirse a nombres propios a secas, mientras que [sustantivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustantivos) se referiría a los demás. En base a ello, **sugiero renombrar [nombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres) a [nombres-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres-propios)**.

Esto se hizo posteriormente en [¿Podéis renombrar la etiqueta "nombres" a "nombres-propios"?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2477/1674)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estoy de acuerdo. Si tenemos una etiqueta `sustantivos`, que la etiqueta `nombres` incluya los sustantivos, a secas, es inconsistente. Y renombrar la etiqueta también me parece buena idea, aclara el significado de la etiqueta.

Comment: Gracias, Gorpik. Esperemos algún día más por si alguien quiere aportar otra visión. Después, re-etiquetaré la pregunta a [tag:feature-request].

Comment: Procedí a juntar ambas etiquetas.