# ¿Podéis renombrar la etiqueta "nombres" a "nombres-propios"?

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado, etiquetas, renombrar-etiquetas

De acuerdo con lo comentado recientemente en [¿Qué diferencia hay entre las etiquetas “nombres” y “sustantivos”?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2475/1674), sería bueno deslindar las etiquetas  [nombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres) y [sustantivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustantivos).

Mi propuesta de renombrar [nombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres) a [nombres-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres-propios) ha cosechado cinco votos positivos y ninguno negativo. Además, [Gorpik respondió](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2476/1674) apoyándola y recibió dos votos positivos y ninguno negativo.

Teniendo en cuenta que poca gente más es activa en el Meta de Spanish Stack Exchange, podemos asumir que hay unanimidad en esta propuesta, por lo que abro esta pregunta como feature-request:

¿Podéis renombrar [nombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres) a [nombres-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres-propios)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aprovechando que ahora puedo hacerlo yo, procedí a hacerlo.

[nombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres) ahora es sinónimo de [nombres-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres-propios), la cual es la principal.