# ¿Necesitamos la etiqueta "sustantivos-propios"? Hagámosla sinónima de "nombres-propios"

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, renombrar-etiquetas

<sub>Actualmente hay bastante jaleo en las etiquetas. Intenté encararlo de una forma bastante genérica en [¡Ordenemos las etiquetas!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674), pero tal vez porque había demasiados elementos a discutir, poco se avanzó.</sub>

<sub>Me propongo pues ir poniendo el foco en algunas e ir aclarando poco a poco.</sub>

---

Existe la etiqueta [sustantivos-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustantivos-propios) con apenas 6 preguntas. No tiene [descripción](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/sustantivos-propios/info) y creo que es susceptible de ser marcada como sinónimo de [nombres-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres-propios) o [sustantivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustantivos), o incluso dejar de utilizarla reetiquetando las preguntas que lo llevan.

Veamos por qué:

- En [¿Qué diferencia hay entre las etiquetas “nombres” y “sustantivos”?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2475/1674) vimos que estas dos etiquetas eran prácticamente iguales, por lo que en...
- [¿Podéis renombrar la etiqueta “nombres” a “nombres-propios”?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2477/1674) se procedió a diferenciarlas.

Así, ahora tenemos:

- [nombres-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres-propios)

  > Preguntas relacionadas con nombres propios o sustantivos. Questions about names or substantives. <sub>[fuente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/nombres-propios/info)</sub>
- [sustantivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustantivos)

  > Para preguntas sobre sustantivos, sus usos, significados, etimología o su gramática. For questions about substantives, its uses, meanings, etymology and grammar. [<sub>fuente</sub>](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/sustantivos/info)

Por tanto, *nombres propios* se usa para preguntas del tipo [¿Por qué Pepe es equivalente a José?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15462/1674), mientras que *sustantivos* para otras del tipo [What do you call pastry in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18307/1674).

Volviendo a [sustantivos-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustantivos-propios), yo abogo por convertirla en sinónimo de [nombres-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres-propios), previa revisión de las seis preguntas que lo llevan, que en algún caso pueden necesitar pasar a llevar la etiqueta [sustantivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustantivos).

¿Qué os parece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy de acuerdo. El término "sustantivos propios" se me hace raro, siempre he usado la expresión "nombres propios", dado que una persona tiene un nombre, no un sustantivo. Si son sólo seis preguntas, yo creo que podríamos reetiquetarlas para que usen la etiqueta [nombres-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres-propios) (o la que proceda), ya que no son muchas, y así no es necesario crear un sinónimo.

Comment: Fantástico. Hecho. Además, deshice el sinónimo que hacía que [proper-nouns] apuntase a [sustantivos-propios]; ahora apunta a [nombres-propios] (Véase la [lista con todos los sinónimos](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all)). En cuanto a [sustantivos-propios], al vaciarla de preguntas se eliminará automáticamente.